# Supabase: policy to allow a specific user by email to select rows doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I'm trying to add a policy to a `policy_test` table in supabase in order to allow only me (with my email) to select rows.

This is the policy I have added:

`table policy_test`

```sql
CREATE POLICY "Only I can select rows from this table"
ON public.policy_test
FOR SELECT USING (
  auth.email() = 'diego@example.com'
);
```

I'm fetching from the Insomnia REST app using my user token as authorization, I'm sure that I'm logged with my user who has `diego@example.com` email, but anyways isn't working.

Result is always: `[]` and it's only returning me the rows if I do deactivate RLS.

Why could this be happening?

I'm following exactly what the documentation says:
https://supabase.com/docs/learn/auth-deep-dive/auth-policies

Comment: Have you tried to use `auth.email() LIKE 'diego****@****.com` instead of using the equal sign? 

Also I would edit your email out of the question...

Comment: Use `LIKE` can cause a security issue, for example an user with email `something_diego@example.com` will be allowed to select rows too.

Comment: Not really, to match `something_diego@example.com`the query would have to be `auth.email() LIKE "%diego@example.com"`

Comment: Doesn't work with `LIKE` either

Comment: Have you looked at the Postgres logs in the Supabase dashboard to try and see what is actually getting executed in the DB?

Comment: Select query is being executed as I see, but nothing related to the policies is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this part of Supabase documentation may help.
[Verifying email domains](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#verifying-email-domains)

> Postgres has a function right(string, n) that returns the rightmost n
> characters of a string. You could use this to match staff member's
> email domains.

```js
-- 1. Create table
create table leaderboard (
  id uuid references auth.users,
  high_score bigint
);

-- 2. Enable RLS
alter table leaderboard
  enable row level security;

-- 3. Create Policy
create policy "Only Blizzard staff can update leaderboard"
  on leaderboard
  for update using (
    right(auth.jwt() ->> 'email', 13) = '@blizzard.com'
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result will only be `[]` if your Row Level Security (RLS) policy is failing. I've just tested this same policy on one of my project and it's working as expected. I also did my test in Insomnia just to be sure there isn't anything weird going on. Please check that you are indeed logged in as that user and are using that user's access token as the Bearer token when making the request. Also you must use the `anon_key` with these requests and not `service_role` key. The `service_role` key bypasses RLS altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about the context of your use case. I am a beginner developer and tried to use Supabase as a database for storing my data. I tried to use NodeJS with the Supabase JavaScript client library to login and fetch data with the policies setting similar to you.

The tutorial from Supabase in your question has a sentence saying `If supabase-js is loaded on your site (in this case http://localhost:3000) it automatically plucks the access_token out of the URL and initiates a session`. For my use case, after calling the login with password function from the supabase client, I found the `session` is empty (`supabase.auth.getSession()`).

I then tried to use `node-fetch` and fetch the data directly using
`${url}/rest/v1/TableName?select=*` with headers:

- `apiKey = YourAnonKey`
- `Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken`

which successfully fetching data from Supabase.
(`accessToken` could be obtained from the returned promise of the login function)

I suspect it is a problem that the context (a backend service) does not work as browser that could initiate a `session`.